# json string cant not converted into json object

Tags: android, json

```
**https://wpsvc5.com/ESAWebAPI/DwgData/018/1821%20Cedar%20Pkwy/Floor%201_BGD.json
```

This is my json file i want to get array value of index(2). I am getting json string as a complete json file data in string but when i am converting into json object it is showing only first index data. i required all data as a object. i am new for json parsing .
**

```
package com.example.swetha.myapplication;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


/**
 * Created by swetha on 12/13/2016.
 */

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) throws JSONException {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
     /*   try {
            //jObj= new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("]")+1));//IndexOf("}") +1));
            //jObj  = new JSONArray(json).getJSONObject(1);
         //   json = json.replace("\\\"","'");
           // jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(1,json.length()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        // return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: what response are you getting from json?? can you show?

Comment: while trying this "jObj= new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}")+1));" i am getting "{"MinX":0,"MaxX":5150.5,"MinY":0,"MaxY":2662.5,"ProjectCode":"018"}" this as a output. And when i use just "jObj = new JSONObject(json);" i am getting exception that value can not be converted as a object.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

json = "{\"Data\":" + json + "}";

jObj = new JSONObject(json);

I have just concatinated my json string like this,and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Example How can you use it

```
String json = "Assuming that here is your JSON response"; 
try {
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("user_details"); 

    //And then read attributes like             
    String name = userDetails.getString("user_name"); 
    String phone = userDetails.getString("user_phone");
    String id = userDetails.getString("re‌​f_id");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above code is for

{"user_details":`{"user_id":"1","user_name":"chand","user_phone":"9620085675","re‌​f_id":6386}}

Answer (score 0):

Shweta,

you are getting JSONArray Response and your trying that JsonArray to JsonObject which is wrong.

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(json);
```

Secondly,you have answered for your question like appending with json format like this,which is not a proper but works.

```
json = "{\"Data\":" + json + "}";
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Make sure your are using JSONArray and parse the data.And one more suggestion,the data getting from that URL is very huge and it may stop your application because of bigger data,use pagination by getting only 10 jsonObjects per request which will improve performance of the application.

Comment: Thanks nithin, but i have to fetch all data at a time..its need of my app. Is there anything else we can do?

Comment: try these references which will work for you.[link1](https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b#.75myrenpe) [link2](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate).This process was implemented in the provided tutorials.

Comment: Actually nithin this is drawing data...all like lines,arcs,circles,texts and much more..so cant do pagination.